# Is There any Way To Change Main Headings of Appboy SDK News page from "News and Alerts" To Something else?

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, iphone-5, ios6.1

I'm currently using appboy SDK in my app.In that we can show News and Alerts Page with the method "displayNews".In this page it is shows a heading with a name "News and Alerts".But i want replace this heading "News and Alerts" with something else according to my client requirement.Is there any way for this ??? Please respond for my problem.

Thanks,
Prakash

Answer (score 0):

Mark CEO of Appboy here. Feel free to email me directly as well, mark@appboy.com

You can't change just the text, but you can add a custom image that you specify. We have some additional options in the current SDK that you can access in AppboySession.h, you'll see a theming object where you can set a few additional properties. Documentation for what each of the below fields configures is in AppboySession.h.

```
[AppboySession theming].sectionHeaderBackgroundImageName = @"table-section-header.png";

[AppboySession theming].navBackButtonImageName = @"navbar-back-btn.png";
[AppboySession theming].navBackButtonHighlightedImageName = @"navbar-back-btn-pressed.png";
[AppboySession theming].navBackgroundImageName = @"navbar-bg-opaque.png";
[AppboySession theming].navBarButtonBackgroundImageName = @"navbar-bar-btn-item.png";
[AppboySession theming].navTitleImageName = @"appboy_title_image.png";
[AppboySession theming].customBodyFont = @"Roboto-Light";
[AppboySession theming].customTitleFont = @"Roboto-Regular";
[AppboySession theming].customHeaderFont = @"Roboto-Condensed";
[AppboySession theming].customImageCornerRadius = 0.0;
[AppboySession theming].customButtonCornerRadius = 0.0;
AppboySession theming].shouldResizeNavigationBarInLandscape = NO;
```

Comment: Hi Mark Thanks for your response.It's great. And i will contact you in the mail with an id prakash.thoram@gmail.com.